# Infer variable type in Java / Eclipse, like C#'s "var"

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut, var, function

I like "var" from C# and "def" from Groovy, and I find writing out types in Java to be a pain.

Say I'm writing code like:

```
List<LongTypeName> results = new ArrayList<LongTypeName>();
```

or

```
Map<TypeNameOne,TypeNameTwo> someLookup = fetchMeMyLookup();
```

What's the easiest way to get this done in Java + Eclipse?

I'm especially interested in the case where I'm not 100% sure what the type will be when I start the line.

My current strategy is to always declare variables as "int", then go back to the start of the line and do "ctrl-1", and accept the type that Eclipse has inferred. Is there any better alternative?

What I would love is to be able to type "def" or "var" and have Eclipse auto-correct this to the correct type as soon as it can figure it out.

(Maybe I should just be programming in Groovy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Type `new ArrayList<LongTypeName>();`
2. Type `Ctrl+2+L` to create a new local variable

Both type type are 'active' - you can tab through them an cycle through selections. In this example, the name proposals are *list* and *arrayList* and the type proposals are all possible interfaces and superclasses of `ArrayList<String>`, : `List<String`, `Collection<String>` etc.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You actually don't need step 2; `Ctrl-2 l` will work just with the cursor positioned after the semicolon (or indeed, anywhere within the statement).

Comment: alt-shift-L also works for me, and is easier to type. I use this all the time now -- thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Type:

```
someLookup = fetchMeMyLookup();
```

Then click on `someLookup` and hit Ctrl+1 for the quick fix of "Create local variable someLookup"

Comment: The create local variable option is the first item in the list so I can nearly always hit Ctrl-1 Enter without inspecting the quick fix dialog. Tis good.

Answer (score 0):

**Java 10** has introduced type inference for local variables. 
You may now use the special (reserved) type name `var`, e.g.:

```
var results = new ArrayList<LongTypeName>();

var someLookup = fetchMeMyLookup();
```

See [JEP 286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) for details.